# android Java code for form action

Tags: android, android-emulator

I did log in form in android ,

How to add the event functionality for this login form,

Now login form display,

I want to add the java code ,

That is When user enter his username and password ,

Get the value into variable and page redirect and system should show , you have enter this username and password ..chk the scrren shot..[image]

My Thread is , What is the java code for log in form ,

In general ,

How to get the textfield  values and how to process It,

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MY_ID);
String password = myText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Ugh, I bet, you meant `EditText` instead of `TextView` :)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidAlerts.aspx?display=Print this site showing sample form example

Comment: i saw some of example, in all that example package name are something like package mina.android.alertsdemo; what is that alertsdemo , and also in other example i saw package name is somthing like package de.vogella.android.temperature; these temperature and alertdemo are already exist in eclips/android i thing ...guide me , if am doing my own  program means , which package should i use,